# Tools for detecting memory leaks for C# and unmanaged C++ application

Tags: c#, c++

We have an application which is developed in the C# .NET Framework 2.0 that is interacting with a COM component(which is developed in C++ unmanaged code).  Sometimes the application throws an out of memory exception(quite hard to reproduce).

We would like to have a tool to find out if we have any memory leaks, and identify the root cause of the memory exception.  What tools would be best for this?  An ideal tool would be able to attach to a running process on a user's machine to do analysis.

We have tried .NET memory profiler but that can only attach to a .NET framework 4.0 running process.  We also used Memory Validator (C++ memory leak detector); however, this tool didn't give us enough hints when attaching to a running process.

Answer (score 3):

Use a memory profiler - they can help to find such leaks, for example:

- http://memprofiler.com/ (commercial, **managed PLUS unmanaged integrated in one profiler**!)
- http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/ (commercial)
- [CLR Profiler from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273) (free)

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

Have you tried [Microsoft Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20028)? It is a very small, I'd daresay minimalistic, but surprisingly powerful tool.

**Long answer**

During my investigation of the memory leak issues, I have used [Microsoft Windbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009), [Microsoft Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20028) and I have thoroughly evaluated [Red Gate ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) (which I have recommend to buy, and I have personally seen recommended to buy by various developers in many different teams), [DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and [.Net Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/).

There is definitively value to get and learn how to use one or more of such tools, perhaps then installed on a virtual development environment hosted on some virtual machine pooled between the developers of the team.

If you evaluate those and any other tool, the big selling point for me would be the ability to investigate memory dumps taken with Windbg, as those are the most easily obtainable even from customers.

Answer (score 0):

try WinDbg and this receipt: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/MemoryLeak.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For the most basic tests, you could use sysinternals procexp.exe to check if you really have a memory leak problem. A lot of COM code would throw out-of-memory, when a null pointer is encountered where one wasn't expected, so the exception code may be misleading.